# Regex multiple pattern replacement

Tags: php, regex

Looking for regex expression (for php) to replace patterns multiple times without affecting remainder. The actual replace required is to reverse certain numbers, 10-1 should be changed to 1-10, i.e. "number1" "dash" "number2" where number is integer (could have more than 1 digit) should be replaced by "number2" "dash" "number1". Note that the pattern does not allow spaces. This pattern can occur any (unknown) number of times including 0.

This text can be surrounded by any other text including numbers, letters, spaces, special characters.

Examples

```
     asdasdasd10-1 2-3asdasd 9-2 2 3XSSADSD
```

should be changed to

```
     asdasdasd1-10 3-2asdasd 2-9 2 3XSSADSD
```

Similarly

```
     <asdasd 10 - 2 dfdsfsdfsdf 8-2
```

changed to

```
     <asdasd 10 - 2 dfdsfsdfsdf 2-8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~(\d+)-(\d+)~', '\2-\1', $yourstring);
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/2), see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- The parentheses around `(\d+)` captures digits to Group 1
- We match the `-`
- The parentheses around `(\d+)` captures digits to Group 2
- `\2-\1` replaces with Group 2 + hyphen + Group 1

**Reference**

- [Capture Group Numbering & Naming: The Gory Details](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)
- [Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

Comment: FYI: Added demo and explanation. :)

Comment: yeah, thanks for sharing this to us :) It is a good learning tool for Regex beginners.

Comment: @0ar.ch IMO the best value is in the articles in the references. :)

Comment: Just saw them. Yup! I like the one by Rex :)

Comment: @anubhava He doesn't seem to be switching them around in the `10 - 2`, just the ones directly in contact like `2-3`

Comment: Above is absolutely perfect. note that (as @zx81 and my second example point out) I only want "nonspace" matches, so first answer is ideal. For your amusement, my key problem was unawareness that preg_replace does multiple patterns by default, I tried (and failed) to construct the repeats in the pattern itself. Hence the question which led to your valuable answer and good reference links.